# DBContext Hell, Proper way to use LINQ calls to a mySQL database

Tags: mysql, multithreading, dbcontext, multitasking

I have been writing a DotNet Core 3.1 app for quite a while when suddenly I am getting thread errors like "System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" when I read a particular item from my SQL table. From all the confusing MS documentation out there, I am told I should be using "await Task.Run(() =>context.tablename.where(x =>x.something == something)"...

But the error does not go away. I have several hundred such calls in my SQLRepository. Do I need to do this for every one of them? That's crazy... The error will not go away. Why has this suddenly started happening. It's not like I am spawning threads manually, just doing calls to mySQL -- why is this not sychronous by default if such calls are not thread-safe? Makes me lose confidence in DotNet Core...

Answer (score 0):

Update: I got it working... And Yes, I did have to use the "await Task.Run() =>" for every db call and that then cascades out so that when you call the method containing the code above, you have to do so using the await keyword... i.e. "await _myDbContext.GetSomething()"

what a pain in the butt...